# Does word2vec make sense for supervised learning?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, word2vec, supervised-learning, unsupervised-learning

I have a list of sentence/label pairs to train the model, how should I encode the sentences as input to, say an SVM?

Answer (score 2):

Are the sentences in the same language?  You could start with the pretrained word2vec file that you can download from Google if it's English. Pay attention to how the train file was created, whether stemming was applied, etc. It's also somewhat important from which corpus it was generated; you'd get different results if this is from newsgroups or if it was extracted from the web or from more formal text.

Word2Vec basically encodes every word into a higher dimensional vector space. This is usually 200,300 or 500 dimensions large. After it is trained, then the "test" sentences are basically bag of words and need not be in any order.

You'd then, for each word in the bag of words, figure out the corresponding word2vec vector. Then you can create features by averaging the vectors, taking the 'minimum', the 'maximum' and if you're comparing text, look at calculating the cosine similarity between vectors. Then use those features in an SVM.